# Android: Informacion del objeto ImageAdapter

Tags: android

Porque algunos metodos de este Objeto ImageAdapter reciben como parametro una posicion pero en ningun momento yo se lo paso y si se lo quito marca error el metodo, aparte tambien donde si utilizo la posicion es en getView pero yo lo tomo como si fuera un for, esta publicacion la hago pasa saber mas hacerca de este objeto.
[ImageAdapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html)

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<Bitmap> imagesList;

public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Bitmap> imagesList){//recibe como parametros el Contexto y un ArrayList de Bitmaps
    this.mContext = context;//se asgina valores
    this.imagesList = imagesList;//se asgina valores
}//./constructor

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return imagesList.size();//se obtiene el tamanio del array list
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {//debe devolver el objeto real en la posición especificada
    return imagesList.get(position);//obtenemos la posicion
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {//debe devolver el ID de la fila del elemento, pero no es necesario aquí.
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(mContext);

    if (imagesList.size() > 0) {
        imageView.setImageBitmap(imagesList.get(position));
    }
    //caracteristicas del ImageView
    imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
    imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(150, 150));

    return imageView;
}
```

}//./clase

Comment: perdon es un objeto

Answer (score 0):

Un Adapter regularmente se llena con una lista de objetos, lo que ser realiza es que obtiene el objeto en esa posición para representarlo en un elemento que alimenta tu adapter.

En este caso se esta obteniendo el objeto de la lista imageList en la posición indicada (position):

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {//debe devolver el objeto real en la posición especificada
    return imagesList.get(position);//obtenemos la posicion
}
```

---

Los métodos `getItem()` y `getItemId()` son métodos del [Adapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html) y esta es su definición:

> [**getItem(int position)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItem(int)): Obtiene el elemento de datos asociado con la
> posición especificada en el conjunto de datos.
>
> [**getItemId(int position)**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Adapter.html#getItemId(int)): Obtiene el id de fila asociada con la posición especificada en la lista.

---

Encontré este tutorial en espanol que me parece completo y esta relacionado a tus últimas preguntas:

**[Tutorial De Listas Y Adaptadores En Android](http://www.hermosaprogramacion.com/2014/10/android-listas-adaptadores/)**

Comment: Hola Elenasys, tengo una duda, es el adaptador de mi GridView? gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(this, bitmaps));//seteo las imagenes al gridView

Comment: pero en si porque esta ahi como parametro posicion, la verdad no le entendi muy bien a la documentacion de Android

Comment: Hola Javier ya ví la documentación Exacto! agregas un adapter de la clase ImageAdapter.

Comment: Veo que la página que me compartes tiene todo el ejemplo.

Comment: que es lo que no entiendes @Javierfr

Comment: Lo de los parametros sioesi

Comment: Por ejemplo getItemId ese metodo espera como parametro una posicion yo lo le paso nada solo copie el ejemplo de la pagina de Android

Comment: Yo no le paso ninguna posicion esta definido en el metodo pero se supone que cuando un metodo tiene parametros, para que funcione ese metodo se los tienes que pasar

Comment: @Javierfr tanto getItemId() y getItem() son métodos del Adapter  agrego esa info en la respuesta...

Comment: La respuesta de @Elenasys es correcta, completa y responde a tus dudas!

Comment: y que hace position en getView?